# Is it acceptable/appropriate to cut a contract short to take a vacation?

Tags: contractors, vacation, contracting, resignation, time-off

I'm currently on a six-month contract and there is a cruise I would like to go on that overlaps with the final days of my contract. I can see a pro and a con to asking for this.

Pro: Taking a vacation at the end of a contract is like taking a vacation between jobs. I was likely going to have a gap in my employment anyway.

Con: If I were to ask for this time off it would be like missing my last day of work. It may be considered some kind of general expectation that everyone is there on their last day so everyone can say goodbye and plan accordingly.

I know the answer to this will likely vary between companies and it all depends on the feelings of the hiring manager, etc. But I'm wondering if anyone has advice or knowledge about the workplace etiquette surrounding this question. When deciding which days off to ask for from work, is it generally considered okay to include your final days among them?

Comment: It's through a staffing agency

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the cruise is during the last five days of your contract and the next five days after.

The possibilities are: (a) No cruise. (b) Take the cruise and major fallout with the company. (c) Agree with the company to shorten the contract or treat it as unpaid holiday. (d) Agree with the company to move the last five days back by 14 days.

You can ask the company if they would agree with (c) or (d). (d) might be actually useful for them if someone took over your job, and 14 days later that person might actually *know* what questions to ask you.